# Xamarin App set event in Android causing Calendar to crash

Tags: c#, android, calendar, xamarin

I am setting a calendar event with the code below.

The event makes it to the selected calendar, but when I click on the event in Calendar I get the "Unfortunately, Calendar has stopped working." crash.

```
setCalendarEvent.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {

        //Set

         //Create Event code
        ContentValues eventValues = new ContentValues ();
        eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.CalendarId, _calId);
        eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Title, "New Sample Event");
        eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Description, "Sample Description");
        eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventTimezone, "Local");
        eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtstart, GetDateTimeMS(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, hour, minute));
        eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtend, GetDateTimeMS(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, (hour + 1), minute));

        var uri = ContentResolver.Insert(CalendarContract.Events.ContentUri, eventValues);
        Console.WriteLine("Uri for new event: {0}", uri);

        long eventID = long.Parse(uri.LastPathSegment);

        ContentValues reminderValues = new ContentValues();
        //reminderValues.Put(CalendarContract.Reminders.InterfaceConsts.CalendarId, _calId);
        reminderValues.Put(CalendarContract.Reminders.InterfaceConsts.EventId, eventID);
        reminderValues.Put(CalendarContract.Reminders.InterfaceConsts.Method, RemindersMethod.Alert.ToString());
        reminderValues.Put(CalendarContract.Reminders.InterfaceConsts.Minutes, 15);

        var reminderUri = ContentResolver.Insert(CalendarContract.Reminders.ContentUri, reminderValues);
        Console.WriteLine("Uri for new event: {0}", reminderUri);
    };
```

I am guessing that there is something wrong with the event data that I am passing over, but I can't figure out what is missing or causing the problem. For a brief moment, sometimes, before the Calendar app crashes I can see a prompt asking if the user is attending with Yes, No and Maybe as options. Not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but you could try adding this to your event extras

.PutExtra(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.AllowedReminders, true)

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced this problem as well, my situation might be a bit different as I was running the code using a Task. But to get it to work I had to explicitly run the insert code on the UI thread using

```
Activity.RunOnUiThread(() => {});
```

I hope this saves some time for someone else

Answer (score -1):

```
            var reminderValues = new ContentValues();
            reminderValues.Put(CalendarContract.Reminders.InterfaceConsts.EventId, eventID);
            reminderValues.Put(CalendarContract.Reminders.InterfaceConsts.Method, (int)RemindersMethod.Alert);
            reminderValues.Put(CalendarContract.Reminders.InterfaceConsts.Minutes, 5);

                }
```

Just the InterfaceConsts.Method part needed to be changed